# How to freeze some items of Combobox to scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I need the custom CheckComboBox with partially scrolled dropdown area. So, I found [this solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18929/An-OwnerDraw-ComboBox-with-CheckBoxes-in-the-Drop) for CheckComboBox. But in my CheckComboBox some items are the simple strings and others presented as checkboxes created using CheckBoxRenderer class. The string items should be freezen and checkboxes should be scrollable. The horizontal line on the pictures below is a simple drawing line just dividing this two item cathegories.

[image]

So, any ideas or maybe some tutorial links (that I couldn't find) would be useful.

Comment: There is an interesting solution on Code Project: [Creating a Custom DropDown Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35068/Creating-a-Custom-DropDown-Control)